# mdpi and hdpi images are not correctly loaded into the device android

Tags: android, image

i have images accordingly int the hdpi and mdpi folder but when i run the application the hdpi images are loading fine on the high resolution devices but when i run on medium resolution 320 x 480 the hdpi images are loading not the medium ones. i have also tested moving the images to res/drawble but nothing happens..  please help me on this
i have set the manifest file with

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your drawable folders are correctly named.

They should be:

- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-hdpi

Also, be sure that your file names are identical. It works fine for me.

Sometimes it may even work to clean the project using Eclipse.

**EDIT:**

I think your project is working fine, but you're making some mistakes with your setup. You probably haven't read the developer guide properly: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Anyway, what you're essentially doing is saying that mdpi = 320 x 480 and hdpi = 480 x 800 pixels. But that's not correct. The DPI (dots per inch) has nothing to do with the actual resolution of the screen. You can easily have a medium DPI screen with a resolution larger than 320 x 480 pixels.

Read the link that I posted - especially the part called "How to Test Your Application on Multiple Screens". That should help you.

Comment: yes, the names are fine and the file names are also identical and tried clean up also... any other suggestion please

Comment: How are you testing the various DPI's?

Comment: The thing is that there's a big difference between the screen size and screen DPI. I.e. it is possible to have a 480 x 800 pixel screen with MDPI density. Try removing the anyDensity tag, and see if that helps.

Comment: No. What I posted is correct, and that's what you should be using. The Android developer guide is excellent if you follow everything it says.